# How to generate thumbnail image for a facebook video?

Tags: php, facebook, video-thumbnails

How can I generate a thumbnail image from a facebook video and store it into a folder.The video url like below

https://www.facebook.com/{user.name}/videos/vb.xxxxx/{VideoID}/?type=2&theater

Regards

Comment: use `facebook-graph-api`

Answer (score 1):

You can probably avoid to generate it yourself. There is a [dedicated api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video-thumbnail/) for this purpose.

The essential part is

```
/* PHP SDK v5.0.0 */
/* make the API call */
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '...?fields={fieldname_of_type_VideoThumbnail}'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
/* handle the result */
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use facebook's Graph API to fetch Video thumbnail of a facebook video .
Below link will help you more to get started.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video

Answer (score -1):

below link will help you to integrate facebook videos with PHP :

https://www.codeofaninja.com/2014/10/display-facebook-video-on-website.html

please mark this answer if it helps you.

Comment: This doesn't really work without the user giving permission. I can't even get my own videos with this method. Also an answer on SO should include the answer, not a link.